# Unable to give style to action bar in android studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to give colour/image as background to the action bar in android studio (), max sdk ver 21, but with no success. What is wrong with the below code and or else how to do it:

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/back</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: did you remember to set this 'sub' styles as toolbar/actionbar style in app theme?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing problem in android lollipop actionbar, then first of all you have to different style.xml file in your res folder named as values-v21.
in this create style.xml as in values folder.

you did not added parent theme correctly. you should create style1 whose parent is style2. In style2 parent add desired theme like `parent="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"`. 
In menifest add style1 as your application theme.

Take a look on example.

Here **colorPrimary** for your action bar,

**colorPrimaryDark** for your notification bar outside application,

**colorAccent** for native dialogs like progressbar, tabs etc.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/material_green_A200</item>


    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

your xml file should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, remember to reference your theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

Also, make sure that in your Java code, you activity extends `ActionBarActivity` instead of just `Activity` as you are using the AppCompat Support Library.

If none of this works, go to your `build.gradle` and check that in the `dependencies` section, you have:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```